# How to remove veracrypt from startup?

Tags: veracrypt

I decrypted the disk, but at the beginning "enter password" still appears, I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and log into Windows. How do I remove this initial veracrypt bootloader entry? Tried to delete it didn't help! It's not in the auto-upload! I even tried reinstalling windows, it still remained!

Answer (score 0):

When Windows boots, open Veracrypt, click on system, then click on permanently decrypt system drive, then restart....it should only take a minute and Veracrypt will be gone forever.
I have to do this every time I restore an image file from a back-up.
Sometimes though I have trouble re-encrypting the restored drive, but that's a minor issue.